# fetchFromGitHub, filter down and use as environment.etc."file".source

Tags: nixos

I'm having some trouble pulling down a file from github and am wondering if someone can help me pull it down and treat it as the text (or source) in my `/etc` folder. Ideally, I'm trying to do something like the following (but using `.text`):

```
environment.etc."sb_hosts".source = (builtins.filterSource
  (path: type: path == "hosts" && type == "regular")
  (fetchFromGitHub {
    owner = "StevenBlack";
    repo = "hosts";
    rev = "v2.1.19";
    sha256 = "1wrwlgcy46vwji0n1imnmlci03ln0v4qd27cw8cwpag57w06n4z7";
  }));
```

But I'm getting an error to the effect of:

```
string '/nix/store/r3xnh6ricqa7lnnbb0ka5vb0h6rw28ap-source' cannot refer to other paths, at /etc/nixos/configuration.nix:13:38
```

For comparison, I can run `fetchFromGitHub` directly with .source and this will pull down the git repo to `/etc/sb_hosts/` as expected.

So far, I've tried to use `builtins.filterSource`, as documented in the [Nix manual: 15.5. Builtin functions](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#ssec-builtins), and I've also tried to use [`cleanSourceWith`](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/lib/sources.nix#L35) -- primarily because I can't find the source of `builtins.filterSource`. Both of these generate the same error, even when I access the `.outPath` of `lib.cleanSourceWith` (which in retrospect, is just calling `filterSource`).

---

<strike>If this is not possible, what is the recommended route to do something like this? The final output is that I would like to collect known, versioned ad-block hosts files from across the web, then merge them with my own local hosts file.</strike>

Edit: I realised after posting that `raw.githubusercontent.com` obeys tagged versions; with `fetchurl` this would answer my original question. Now I'm just wondering why the above codeblock doesn't work and how I would acheive something of the same effect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get a single file/subdirectory using `path`+`string`-concatenation.

```
environment.etc."sb_hosts".source =
  fetchFromGitHub {
    owner = "StevenBlack";
    repo = "hosts";
    rev = "v2.1.19";
    sha256 = "1wrwlgcy46vwji0n1imnmlci03ln0v4qd27cw8cwpag57w06n4z7";
  } + "/hosts";
```

## Why does this work?

You can concatenate a path with a string to refer to a subpath (it will also be a `path`). Derivations (such as `fetchFromGitHub args`) implicitly coerce to the path that they will produce once built.

## Why didn't the proposed solution in the question work?

`builtins.filterSource` (and its siblings, `lib.cleanSource{,With}`) will copy a `path` into the store, after removing all files that do not pass the predicate. Notably, the store copy (and the corresponding caching) happens *after* the predicate is applied.

This is primarily useful for Nix definitions that are inline with the source code they're packaging, to avoid causing rebuilds when irrelevant files (such as `__pycache__` or the `.git` folder) change.

That wouldn't make much sense for derivations, since they are *already* in the Nix store, and are identified by their build inputs rather than by their output.

## What does the error message mean?

`/nix/store/r3xnh6ricqa7lnnbb0ka5vb0h6rw28ap-source` is the output of a derivation, so Nix enforces that it exists (or is built) before anything that uses it can be built in turn. Why they chose to call this relationship `refers` is far beyond my understanding.

## Solving the *actual* problem

You can add extra entries to your `/etc/hosts` using the [networking.extraHosts](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/release-18.09/nixos/modules/config/networking.nix) option. This property expects the contents directly as a string, but that can be solved using [builtins.readFile](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#ssec-builtins).

Thus:

```
networking.extraHosts = builtins.readFile
  (fetchFromGitHub {
    owner = "StevenBlack";
    repo = "hosts";
    rev = "v2.1.19";
    sha256 = "1wrwlgcy46vwji0n1imnmlci03ln0v4qd27cw8cwpag57w06n4z7";
  } + "/hosts");
```

Comment: Ah! perfect! thank you for the detailed answer and more correct solution!